# Iphone app crashed due to memory pressure

Tags: ios, iphone, memory-leaks, cgcontext

I am generating image from view using following functions

```
- (UIImage *)imageByRenderingView
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.bounds.size);
    [self.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *resultingImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return resultingImage;
}
```

But as the number of times this function is called is get increased , app get crashed.
How can I optimize this function or any alternative function to generate image from view which will not result into crash.

Comment: are you using the ARC?

Comment: Did you check with Static Analyser?

Comment: u were using the much more images

Comment: I am not sure what's wrong in this code but you should put your code into @autorelasepool block

Comment: I have also tried using @autoreleasepool wherever I am calling this function, but doesn't work

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik but it is needed, that to generate image of UIView

Comment: reduce the pixel size and remove the unwanted NSLog in ur xcode

Comment: @Retro I have checked with instruments tool, but it is not showing any memory leaks around this function. And whenever I comment out this function app runs without any crash.

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik how will it help to reduce memory use?

Comment: Maybe the problem is not in this method. What do you do with the returned images? Are you keeping them all in memory?

Comment: yes I am adding them in one NSMutableArray, ya this can be the reason. If so how and where can I save these generated images?